# Angular Resource: Error: $resource:badcfg

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have looked at other posts here but still can't resolve my issue.

I get a Error:

> $resource:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter

I believe this error is caused by it returning an array rather than an object or vice versa.

Here's my code:

Inside my factory(I added the isArray: false but still not luck)

```
var task = $resource('http://localhost:5000/task/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    'get': {method:'GET', isArray: false},
});
```

Then in the return section of my factory

```
    find: function(id){
      return task.get({ id: id });
    }
```

In my Flask server it does the correct response when I load the page:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2017 14:35:13] "GET /task/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However I still get the error?

Also this is what my server provides if i put it in the browser
http://localhost:5000/task/1

```
[{"completed": true, "id": 1, "ownerName": "Ryan", "task": "Test Activity", "title": "A test task"}]
```

Iv also tried this and get the same error:

```
console.log(task.get({ id: 1 }));
```

Comment: can you configure your server to return an object rather than an array with a single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error occurs when the `$resource` service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except `query` which expects arrays.
>
> To resolve this error, make sure your `$resource` configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.
>
> [--AngularJS Error Reference - $resource:badcfg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg)

The default actions for $resource are:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Avoid changing the default method:

```
var task = $resource('http://localhost:5000/task/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    //AVOID changing default
    //'get': {method:'GET', isArray: true},
});
```

Instead use the `query` action method:

```
find: function(id){
  //return task.get({ id: id });
  //INSTEAD use query action method
  return task.query({ id: id });
}
```

This will avoid confusing programmers that are familiar with the conventions of the $resource service.

For more information, see [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

---

### Using `transformResponse` to Extract Object from Array

If the server is erroneously returning the resource object enclosed in an array, it can be extracted with a response transform function:

```
var task = $resource('http://localhost:5000/task/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    'get': {method:'GET',
            transformResponse: function(json) {
                var data = angular.fromJson(json);
                if ((typeof data == 'array' && (data.length == 1)) {
                   return data[0];
                } else {
                   return data;
                };
            } 
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with something like:

```
var task = $resource('http://localhost:5000/task/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    'get': {method:'GET', isArray: false},
  });
```

You've missed {id:'@id'} to pass paramter id

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to set isArray: false to true
so:

```
  var task = $resource('http://localhost:5000/task/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    'get': {method:'GET', isArray: true},
  });
```

Comment: I think it would be better to change you API signature and implementation. A `get` with id parameter should return one object, not an array

Comment: This is true, although I was not able to edit the API in the task hence the headache :/ but thanks for the suggestion